# Django GET request in AJAX

Tags: ajax, django

I need to get some HTML using AJAX.
My view work fine as long as I use jQuery:

#### view.py

```
def my_ajax(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        my_form = MyForm()
        context = {
            'form': my_form
        }
        return render(request, 'myapp/form.html', context)
```

#### main.js (jQuery load)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#foo').click(function() {
        $('#bar').load('{% url "myapp:form" %}');
    });
});
```

If I use the JavaScript `XMLHttpRequest` I have to remove `if request.is_ajax():` from the view otherwise I got the error `The view myapp.views.my_ajax didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

#### main.js (XMLHttpRequest)

```
(function() {
    document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener("click", function() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("bar").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", '{% url "myapp:form" %}', true);
    xhttp.send();
    }, false);
})();
```

What I'm doing wrong in the **XMLHttpRequest**?
I am surely missing something but I would like to use Vanilla JavaScript this time.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you running `main.js` through a template generator?  If not, then it will always send with the actual literal `'{% url "myapp:form" %}'` in the JavaScript file.  The only template tags that will get expanded have to be in the form.html template that you are rendering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add `xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');` after `var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();`.

Comment: Thank you... Actually I had to place it after `xhttp.open("GET", '{% url "myapp:form" %}', true);`.

Comment: I updated the answer as it needs to be `XMLHttpRequest` and NOT `XmlHttpRequest`:)